# Lightweight solution to block sites on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, blacklist

I want to block blacklisted sites on a local PC. 
The admin part should be protected by password.
Could anybody recomends a Lightweight solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you will go to that PC and do this your self, can make yourself admin, go to the hosts file add all the blacklisted sites and point them to google or some other site. General users can be non admins and thus wont be able to edit this file.

On my windows I need to copy the hosts file from its location:

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

To a new folder like d:\mystuff\ , edit it there, then copy it back to itsdefault location, say yes to the UAC and its done.

Sample extract

> ## 38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
>
> ## localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
>
> ## 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> ## ::1             localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1 bad.com

Here replace bad.com with the blacklisted domain name. Similarly make new rows for each domain

Comment: I know about hosts. But it is not suitable for my situation :( I really need a software.

Comment: There are local proxy apps that do that. again depends if its in a lan or a local internet connection. if local then user should not be an admin